# what is an efficient way to fulfill this simple task?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

```
5048,3293,5242,3290,5244,3411,5050,3414
```

In this example 5048-5242-5244-5050 are from the same "family"
same for 3293-3290-3411-3414 basically it's every other term .
the end result i want and expect is the highest of the first "family" next to the highest of the second family and the lowet next to the lowest having the following end result.

```
['5242', '3414', '5048', '3290']
```

It can be easily done using 2 lists each having a +2 index one starting at 0 the other at 1 etc.. but what is an actually efficient pythonic way to do it.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
numbers = [5048,3293,5242,3290,5244,3411,5050,3414]

f3 = [n for n in numbers if str(n)[0] == '3']
f5 = [n for n in numbers if str(n)[0] == '5']

newList = [max(f5), max(f3), min(f5), min(f3)]
```